# Zabbix: filter discovery action by IP address

Tags: zabbix

I'm currently monitoring several routers I have in my network with Zabbix 3.4.4. I'm now adding them manually but I'd like to use the discovery feature to do this automatically. The problem I have is that I need to monitor only the router, and not all other hosts on the net.

For example: I have a discovery rule for 10.0.0.0/16, I add a new network 10.0.10.0/24 which has several hosts, but **I want to monitor only** 10.0.10.1. Sadly being routers and from different manufacturers I cannot test services or responses, I can rely on ping only.

From what I see in the Action options there's no way to filter for such option, am I right? Is there any other way to filter hosts IPs so that I can add Zabbix monitoring only to router's IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the benefit of repeatedly scanning the whole subnet just to find a small number of hosts is just not there. I'd suggest looking into creating those hosts via API instead.

Having said that, a range of `10.0.0-255.1` might work, and also reduce your network traffic significantly.

Comment: Indeed it has been accepted as value, clever! I just hope this doesn't mean from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.255.1 anyway. Since when I've changed the  IP range Zabbix kept discovering IPs but not only .1 ones.

Comment: The correct range is `10.0.0-255.1-1`, I'm accepting the answer. thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that plain `.1` did not work as expected and you had to use `.1-1`? If so, what happened in the first case?

Comment: Yes, when I **changed** the discovery rule it kept on discovering all IPs.  Then I deleted the rule and created a new one with the new range and in less than 1h I had just the desired IPs. Not sure if the *ongoing* discovery was updated with the new range while running

Comment: Ah, OK - the ongoing one would definitely not be updated with changes from the DB. To be sure, you can change it back to plain `.1` and observe the outcome.